# Why does Pakku crash with 'Cannot locate native library libarchive.13.dylib' while using on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, raku

I'm using macOS Big Sur and trying to install Raku module like `pakku add App::RaCoCo`. I will get a message:

```
Cannot locate native library 'libarchive.13.dylib': dlopen(libarchive.13.dylib, 10): image not found
```

Environment:

```
> raku -v
Welcome to ™ v2021.09.
Implementing the ™ programming language v6.d.
Built on MoarVM version 2021.09.

Pakku> git show --pretty=reference --no-patch
09fb5c7 (Add missing space separator between `pakkuopt` in `help` command, 2021-04-17)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It happens because of the Archive::Libarchive::Raw module cannot find `libarchive.13.dylib` library in the default paths and crashes.

To fix it you need to install `libarchive` through brew and make a link for `libarchive.13.dylib` library:

```
brew install libarchive
ln -s /usr/local/opt/libarchive/lib/libarchive.13.dylib /usr/local/lib/
```